# Lots of ThreadLocalMap entries in memory

Tags: java, jvm, thread-local

Consider a very large Java VM with a great many threads running a web server.

Now consider a sample of the output generated by `jmap -histo` that looks something like this:

```
  4:       5989163      191653216  java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry
 10:         46786       49012000  [Ljava.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry;
 86:         23384        2619008  java.lang.Thread
144:         46750        1122000  java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap
```

If you do the division, it turns out we have 256 instances of `java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry` per thread. Kind of a high number, and more than I'd expect given that most of the ThreadLocals shouldn't be storing a whole lot of values. I don't see that many in Tomcat when I use its ThreadLocal-leak-detection feature.

Any reason these ThreadLocalMaps should be so memory-hungry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be running into this bug:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6625723

Answer (score 1):

Can you figure out what the values in the thread local map are?  Have you poked around with `jhat` or equivalent to see what they're referencing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the actual number of thread locals, not the values that they contain.

I suspect that you might be using ThreadLocal incorrectly.  The `ThreadLocal` object should be created (once) and assigned to a `static` variable, as shown in the example in [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

If you create the `ThreadLocal` object in the initializer of a non-static variable, then each time the variable declaration is executed you get a new thread local.  If you combine this with thread pooling, then you'll get lots of useless thread local map entries.